# Взаимная аутентификация по протоколу SSL Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssl, openssl

Настраиваю взаимную аутентификацию сервера и клиента по протоколу SSL. На клиенте (Windows 7) и сервере (Windows Server 2008 R2) создаю хранилища с помощью Oracle Wallet Manager (OWM), далее в OWM создаю запросы на сертификаты для клиента и сервера, как на картинке ниже.

[image: Запрос сертификата в OWM]

В OpenSSL выпускаю корневой сертификат:

```
openssl> genrsa -out root.key 2048 

openssl> req -x509 -new -key root.key -days 1000 -out root.crt
```

Далее, там же создаю запрос на сертификат

```
openssl> genrsa -out serv.key 2048

openssl> req -new –key serv.key –out serv.csr
```

В созданный OpenSSL *.csr файл копирую содержимое запроса из OWM, создаю сертификат и подписываю его корневым.

```
openssl> x509 -req –in serv.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out serv.crt -days 500
```

Аналогично создаю сертификат клиента, подписанный корневым.
Далее в OWM на сервере Oracle импортирую корневой сертификат (Import Trusted Certificate) и сертификат сервера (Import User Certificate). На клиенте так же импортирую корневой сертификат и сертификат клиента. Сохраняю и устанавливаю галочку "Auto Login" хранилища.

Далее настраиваю соединение (Net Manager -> Local -> Profile -> Oracle Advanced Security -> SSL) на обеих машинах. В результате на сервере в файл listener.ora добавляются строки

> SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
>
> WALLET_LOCATION =   (SOURCE =
>       (METHOD = FILE)
>       (METHOD_DATA =
>         (DIRECTORY = C:\OraWallet)
>       )   )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = WIN-QV6N8G35RD5.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = WIN-QV6N8G35RD5.localdomain)(PORT = 2484))
>       )   )

На клиенте добавляю соединение "TCP/IP with SSL". При попытке его тестирования появляется сообщение об ошибке

> ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully

. В результате трассировки на сервере, в файле появляются 2 подряд сообщения об ошибках

> TNS-12560:TNS: protocol adapter error

и

> TNS-00540:SSL protocol adapter failure

Перепробовал все, что советуют в интернет, но так и не решил проблему. Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась путём использования orapki для создания кошельков и сертификатов на сервере и клиенте. [Этот гайд](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/HOW-TO--Setting-up-Encrypted-Communications-Channels-in-Oracle-Database/) помог решить проблему.